# Incorrect indefinite integral on MATLAB?

Tags: integration, matlab, indefinite-integrals

any ideas why matlab is giving me an incorrect answer here?

**1 set of commands**

> > syms x L N2
> >
> > N2 = 6*x/L^2 - 2/L^2

N2 =

(6*x)/L^2 - 2/L^2

> > expand(int(N2*N2))

ans =

(4*x)/L^4 - 4/(9*L^4) - (12*x^2)/L^4 + (12*x^3)/L^4

The term 4/(9*L^4) should not be there, I have no idea where it is coming from...

If it is a constant, then why does the following integration yield no constant, since it is the same mathematical operation?:

**2nd set of commands**

> > expand(int(4/L^4 - (24*x)/L^4 + (36*x^2)/L^4))

ans =

(4*x)/L^4 - (12*x^2)/L^4 + (12*x^3)/L^4

> > 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indefinite integrals have an arbitrary constant term. This one is as good as any other real number.

Even if Matlab gives different answers when doing identical calls, it's not *mathematically* wrong.

On the other hand, [Matlab manual](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/int.html) states that ***Results returned by int do not include integration constants.*** (see More about $\to$ Tips) If this means the constant must always be $0$, it may be considered a bug, and you could ask directly to Mathworks. But this is a narrow interpretation of the statement, and it could as well mean that Matlab will not add a $+ C$ at the end on purpose.

However, bear in mind that even without an integration constant, the answer is ambiguous, when the primitive may be given in different but equivalent forms, like

$$\int \frac{\mathrm dx}{2\cosh x}=\arctan \left(\tanh \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)+C=\arctan\left(e^x\right)+C'$$

Whereas $\arctan\left(e^x\right)\neq\arctan \left(\tanh \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)$, and the difference is of course a constant, $\pi/4$. So, what does it mean here to *not include integration constants*?

Comment: Ok, in that case why does the following result not include the arbitrary constant, since it is the same function that is being integrated?                                                       >> expand(int(4/L^4 - (24*x)/L^4 + (36*x^2)/L^4))
 
ans =
 
(4*x)/L^4 - (12*x^2)/L^4 + (12*x^3)/L^4
 
>>

Comment: @user32882: arbitrary means arbitrary, it does not mean zero.

Comment: right, so why is the second set of commands not yielding a constant AT ALL?

Comment: @user32882 See edit